# Building OpenJDK - missing antlr3

Tags: linux, gradle, antlr, antlr3, java

I'm attempting to build OpenJDK but getting an error from gradle that says:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/pi/openjdk/rt/buildSrc/build.gradle' line: 86

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'buildSrc'.
Cause: Could not find method antlr3() for arguments [{group=org.antlr, 
name=antlr-runtime, version=3.1.3}] on root project 'buildSrc'.
```

I have antlr3 installed and in my classpath.  The command

```
java org.antlr.Tool -version
```

returns

```
ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 3.5.2
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try removing `3.5.2` and installing (adding to your CP) version `3.1.3`.

Comment: Sounds like some problem with the build, not a problem with ANTLR. (A missing dependency would result in a different error message. I don't know that particular build, but hopefully it isn't necessary to install anything manually.) Double-check that you are using the correct Gradle version required by the build. If the build provides a `gradlew` script, use that instead of a manual Gradle installation.

Comment: Both of those tips seem to have helped. It turned out I had Gradle version 1.0 and the OpenJDK page suggested 1.8.  So I updated to that and it downloaded Antlr 3.1.3 for me.

Comment: LOL! Well I got past the problem of the wrong version of Antlr and now it tells me `Unknown and unsupported build architecture: arm`.  Apparently you can't actually build for ARM on an ARM system. I'll have to try on my desktop Linux and then transfer it over. Sigh.  Thanks for the help.